# Action vs ActionListener for multiple buttons with the same java

Tags: java, action, actionlistener

I would like to clarify my understanding of using Action instead of ActionListener.

If I have multiple JButtons that all require the same function to occur if they are clicked (for example the button will be disabled), would using Action be more appropriate for this?

If so, is it because you can change the state of the button (for example making it disabled) by setting the state of the Action to disabled?

Is this not possible with an actionListener?

Below is some code demonstrating the example given above:

```
JButton[] button = new JButton[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    button[i] = new JButton();
    Action buttonAction = new ButtonAction();
    button[i].setAction(buttonAction);  
}

class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Sorry if I have got the wrong end of the stick!

Thank you!

Comment: In my experience, a more common situation is when you want an action to be accessible from multiple _types_ of controls.  For example, I might have a menu item, a toolbar button, and a right-click context menu item all tied to the same `Action`.

Comment: one and another are event handlers.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html):

> The Action interface provides a useful extension to the ActionListener interface in cases where the same functionality may be accessed by several controls.

So I'd agree with your assertion that this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

Extending the AbstractAction gives You the ability to add additional infos in the same way at one point in Your code:

```
public class NewFileAction extends AbstractAction
{
 /**
   * 
   */
protected NewFileAction()
{
  super("NewFile");
  this.putValue(NAME, "New File");
  this.putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "New file");
  this.putValue(LONG_DESCRIPTION, "New file");
  this.putValue(SMALL_ICON,ImageIconFactory.getSmallImageIcon(ImageIconFactory.Option.SUN_New24));
}
```

The same information will then automatically appear on any button, MenuItem, etc.

A remark on Your example:
Normally You do not want to create many Actions like

```
Action buttonAction = new ButtonAction();
```

in your loop. You will normally have one Action object and reuse it in all the MenuItems, Buttons, etc. 
A typical exception to this is if the behaviour of Your action changes on a parameter passed in the constructor.

```
Action buttonAction = new ButtonAction(loopCounter);
```

In this case many action objects may be useful - also the loopCounter might go to the labels, etc.